# Counting up numeric query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a cinema database and I'm stuck on a certain point in my insert script.
Im creating tickets and I need a totalprice, this price is the sum of two values that I search using several subquerys. 
Here are the two querys

```
Select toelage 
from klanttype
where type = 
        (
        Select type
        from klant
        where klantnr = (
                          Select klantId
                          from Verkoop
                          where verkoopId = 2512
        )
        );

select toelage 
from zetelzone
where zone = (
              select zone
              from zetel
              where zetelnr = 130
);
```

I'm now stuck on adding the two values together to create one number to insert into the Ticket table.

Comment: The semicolon there was from testing phase, to check the both individual querys for their own result. those are the two query from wich the results must be added

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up both queries via a union all.
this is also easily expanded to multiple source destinations

```
select sum(toelage)
from (
   Select toelage 
   from klanttype
   where type = 
     (
     Select type
     from klant
     where klantnr = (
                      Select klantId
                      from Verkoop
                      where verkoopId = 2512
     )
     )
   UNION ALL
   select toelage 
   from zetelzone
   where zone = (
          select zone
          from zetel
          where zetelnr = 130
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with a join and a sub query :

```
SELECT t.toelage + (SELECT p.toelage
                    FROM zetelzone p
                    JOIN zetel pp 
                     ON p.zone = pp.zone and pp.zetelnr = 130 )
FROM klanttype t
JOIN klant s 
 ON t.kantnr = s.kantid and s.verkoopId = 2512
```

That is if these queries return 1 record. If the sub query return more than that, you need a different approach like another join or to correlate it.

Comment: I had to alter it a bit, but the logic from your query solved the problem. Thank you very much for your assistence!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine and sum with union all

```
select sum(toelage) as toelage from (
    Select toelage 
    from klanttype
    where type = 
            (
            Select type
            from klant
            where klantnr = (
                              Select klantId
                              from Verkoop
                              where verkoopId = 2512
            )
            )
    union all
    select toelage 
    from zetelzone
    where zone = (
                  select zone
                  from zetel
                  where zetelnr = 130
    )
) as allSubQuerys
```